# Как реализовать эту функцию? С

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Изменяет направление луча т.е. приращения его координат, в зависимости от вида зеркала,на которое падает луч. Луч распространяется только горизонтально или вертикально param [in|out] increase - массив с приращениями координат луча:

- `increase[0]` - приращение по y,
- `increase[1]` - приращение по x

param [in] mirror - вид зеркала:

- `+1` - под углом 135 градусов, сохраняет знак приращения
- `-1` - под углом 45 градусов, обращает знак приращения
- произвольное другое значение - не является зеркалом

Прототип:

```
void turnRay(int increase[2], int mirror);
```

Правильно ли сделать вот так:

```
void turnRay_0(int increase[2], int mirror)
{
    int i;
    if (mirror == 1 || mirror == -1)
    {
        int temp = increase[0];
        increase[0] = increase[1];
        increase[1] = temp;
        i = (increase[0] > increase[1]) ? 0 : 1;
        increase[i] *= (mirror == 1 || mirror == -1) ? mirror : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Я не C-шник, но вот что можно сократить:  
  increase[i] *= mirror == -1 ? mirror : 1;

Comment: @Miron А я Сишник, так-что упрощаю так : `increase[i] *= mirror ;`.

Answer (score -1):

Неправильно передается массив в функцию. Элементы массива с индексом , отличным от два могут быть невидимы в теле функции. Массив передается по указателю - int *arr. А далее , разименоваешь указатель и получаешь доступ к элементам массива,

Comment: Тут предусмотренно что как раз будет 2 элемента)

Comment: Здесь конкретно, передается элемент массива с индексом 2.

Comment: Параметр `int arr[2]` значит абсолютно то же самое, что и `int *arr`.

Comment: Совсем не одно и то же. В первом случае доступ по индексу к конкретной ячейке, во втором можно получить произвольный дрступ

Comment: @MAXXRYAZANOFF, если бы `arr[2]` передавалось в функцию как фактический параметр, то это была бы передача в функцию одного элемента массива с индексом 2. А в данном случае это тип аргумента - массив размером 2. Посмотрите на вывод, совершенно очевидно что в функцию пришел не один элемент, а указатель на массив: https://ideone.com/nFUEFy